# Pomodoro Clock not Stopping after countdown

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, timer

The clock works until it gets to zero which is where it is supposed to start the break timer. the issue is that it gets to zero then starts counting down in negative numbers. here is the function that has that code. By the way, I have the interval at 100 so I do not have to wait a long time when testing the clock.

```
//This function is the culprit
function start(){
    $("#start").addClass("disabled");
    $("#myreset").addClass("disabled");
    var secs = Number("59");

    var min = document.getElementById("sessiontime").innerHTML; 
    min = min-=1;

    if(min > -1){
        startcounter = setInterval(function(){
            secs--;

            if(secs > 9){
                document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = min +":"+ secs;
            } else if(secs >=0 && secs < 10){
                secs = "0"+secs;
                document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = min +":"+ secs;
            } else if(secs < 0){
                min--;
                secs = 59;
            } else if(secs === 0 && min === 0){
                clearInterval(startcounter); 
                var x = document.getElementById("arrownumid").innerHTML;
                mybreak(x);
            }
        },100);
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/sammyb123/pen/QyQaPr

Comment: Try setting this up in https://jsfiddle.net/ That will help us to help you debug it.

Comment: I am not familiar with fiddle but here is codepen http://codepen.io/sammyb123/pen/QyQaPr

Comment: Try putting `console.log` statements in strategic places in your code, to see what gets executed. Or use the Javascript debugger for your favorite browser (press F12) and set breakpoints in your code.

Comment: Question to ask yourself: What will happen when secs is 0? Which branch of the if statement will execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out, may not be the most efficient but it does what it is supposed to do. Thank you for taking the time to help.

```
function start(){
    $("#start").addClass("disabled");
    $("#myreset").addClass("disabled");

    var secs = Number("59");
    var min = document.getElementById("sessiontime").innerHTML; 
    min = min-=1;

    if(min>=0){
       startcounter = setInterval(function(){
       secs--;

          if(secs > 9){
             document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = min +":"+ secs;
                } if(secs >0 && secs < 10){
                   secs = "0"+secs;
                   document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = min +":"+ secs;
                      } if(secs ===0 && min >0){
                           min--;
                           secs = 59;
                         } 

                              else if(min ===0 && secs ===0){
                                 document.getElementById("beep").play();
                                 stop(startcounter);
                                 clearInterval(startcounter); 
                                 var x = document.getElementById("arrownumid").innerHTML;
                                  mybreak(x);
                              }
                      },1000);
                   }
                }
```